# jQuery not working on second item of same category

Tags: jquery, css

The following code creates different colored gradient overlays on archive posts on a Wordpress site. The jQuery checks for a value (letter designation) in the category field of the custom post type and assigns a different overlay depending on what is there. If the same letter designation is used twice, the overlay only works on the first one. Subsequent posts with the same letter don't get the overlay. I'm new to JQuery and have no idea why.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="box">
[wpbb-if post:featured_image]
<div class="fl-post-image">
    [wpbb post:featured_image size="large" display="tag" linked="yes"]
</div>
[/wpbb-if]

    <div class="category">
        [wpbb post:custom_field key='category']
    </div>

    <div class="label">
        [wpbb post:custom_field key='label']
    </div>

</div>
```

And here's the jQuery (for now all the overlays are the same gray gradient):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var redoverlay = $(".category:contains('D')").parents().eq(1);
    $(redoverlay).hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('overlay red',500);
    });
    var greenoverlay = $(".category:contains('F')").parents().eq(1);   
    $(greenoverlay).hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('overlay green',500);
    });
    var blueoverlay = $(".category:contains('C')").parents().eq(1);   
    $(blueoverlay).hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('overlay blue',500);
    });
    var orangeoverlay = $(".category:contains('L')").parents().eq(1);   
    $(orangeoverlay).hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('overlay orange',500);
    });
});
```

And the CSS:

```
    /* Just changes the cursor to a pointer when hovering over an image */
.box:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Makes the letter appear on hover */
.box:hover .category{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s;
}

/* Makes the title appear on hover */
.box:hover .label{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s;
}

/* Speed of overlay */
.overlay{
    position: relative;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease;
}

/* Controls the position of the graduated overlay */
.overlay:after{
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0;
}

/* Controls the opacity of the overlay on hover and makes the overlay 'click-transparent' so clicking will hit the linked image underneath and not the overlay, which would result in not going anywhere */
.overlay:hover:after{
    opacity: .75;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* Controls the graduated tone of the overlays. This can be reproduced by going here: https://www.cssmatic.com/ and select Gradient Generator. Currently all are set to grey  */
.red:after{
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(204,204,204,0)), color-stop(71%, rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(204,204,204,1)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
}

.blue:after{
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(204,204,204,0)), color-stop(71%, rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(204,204,204,1)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
}

.green:after{
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(204,204,204,0)), color-stop(71%, rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(204,204,204,1)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
}

.orange:after{
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(204,204,204,0)), color-stop(71%, rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(204,204,204,1)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 71%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
}
```

Comment: Since posting this the client has had me change the overlays to straight css, all the same color, so checking the site won't help at this point. Hopefully someone can envision what I'm getting at and tell my why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.eq(1)` restricts the array to just the one value at the particular index. So you are only getting 1 parent instead of all parents. https://api.jquery.com/eq/

If I understand what you want, I believe what you need is:

```
// red overlays
$(".category:contains('D')").parents(".box").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('overlay');
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('overlay');
        $(this).removeClass('red');
    });
});
```

Comment: Added edit to include code for what I think you want.

Comment: Edited: I'm not sure the `.hover()` works the way you had presented. If it does, great, but as far as I know, it takes 2 function parameters, one for over and one for off.

Comment: Thx. I'll try this on my copy as soon as I transfer the site to my client's host. I need to solve this anyway as he's not the first client to ask for different post categories to look different on an archive page. I did not know that about eq so appreciate the input.